# Is there an optimal way to find the minimum distance from an ellipse to a point without traversing every point in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, package

I need an algorithm that requires the minimum distance between a conic section's perimeter and a point.

So far, I've tried navigating the conic for if the orthogonal vector from the perimeter passed through the the point. But this is too makeshift and there is still scope for an error (because you may miss a point).

I was wondering if there's any library in python that calculates this?

I should make it clear that that the conic formula will be like this: `ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey +f = 0`

Comment: Note that the minimum distance corresponds to a line perpendicular to the ellipse, and parallel to the point. In that case, if you know how to describe the ellipse in terms of x and y, you can calculate the distance explicitly?

Comment: It boils down to solving a quartic equation, so Newton-Raphson could be a viable alternative.

Comment: It's exactly the problem of computing altitude above earth ellipsoid, so you'll find an algorithm for sure in some geographical package, wgs84 for example

Comment: The way you are doing it is a good start. There are ways to formalize the process of getting closer to a maximum or minimum by looking at one point after another. A web search for "numerical minimization one dimension" and in particular "golden section method" should find some resources for you.